# PHPで使用するデバッグツールについて

Tags: php

PHPがメインの開発言語でXAMPPを使用している現場の場合、デバッグツールは何を使用しているのが一般的ですか。コードにブレークポイントを張って変数の中を確かめるといったデバックツールを使用しているのか知りたいと思っています。
デバッグツールを使わない現場もあるのでしょうか。

Comment: 重複候補 - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/7068/3060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

経験則ですが、Xdebugなどブレークポイントデバッガは半数位の現場で使用されているイメージです。
意外とecho・ロギング・フレームワークのDebug機能のみで対処してる現場は多いです。

Xampp導入～Xdebug設定のための手順も記載しておきます。

1. Disable IIS

   1. Control Panel
   2. Programs and Features
   3. Turn Windows features on or off
   4. Internet Information Service
2. Download & unzip Xampp

   1. e.g. https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.2.3/
3. Put it on C:\
4. Download and setup php X Debug TS 32bit

   1. e.g. https://xdebug.org/files/php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15.dll
   2. Put it on \php\ext
   3. Add settings to \php\php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.2-vc15.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="c:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

5. Run xampp-control.exe, and start Apache & MySQL

Confirm versions by shell of xampp

```
httpd -v
mysql -v
php -v
```

Supplement

1. Web server's document-root is htdocs.
2. Web site url is localhost.

↑ココまでがサーバ側（Xampp）の設定。

↓以降はエディタ側の設定（例としてVisual Studio Codeで設定）

Install

```
1. Visual Studio Code (by installer)
2. Add PHP Debug extension
```

1. 市販ウイルス対策ソフト、Windows Defenderなどのファイアーウォールのポート9000を開ける
2. Visual Studio Codeで開く
3. デバッグ実行
4. どの環境で初期化するか聞かれる

   - 拡張で入れたPHPを選択
   - .vscode/launch.jsonが自動生成
5. launch.json書き換え

```js
{
    // IntelliSense を使用して利用可能な属性を学べます。
    // 既存の属性の説明をホバーして表示します。
    // 詳細情報は次を確認してください: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

※１　作業フォルダ（pathMappings）などの位置関係は、環境に応じて調整してください
※２　なお個人的にはXamppは非推奨で、各個人がCentOSのVM立てた方が間違いが少ないかなーと思ってます

Answer (score 1):

Xdebug + Visual Studio Code が軽くて使いやすいですね。

Eclipseを使っていましたが、動作が重いのが難点です。